# Android: Get screen resolution or Lost in API versions

Tags: android, api

I try to read out the screen resolution of a device programatically. I want my app to support all API versions from 4. Well, unfortunatly, the API to read the resolution has beenn changed from version 12 to 13.

This is my code:

```
int Measuredwidth = 0;
int Measuredheight = 0;

WindowManager w = getWindowManager();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
  Point size = new Point();
  w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
  Measuredwidth = size.x;
  Measuredheight = size.y;
} else {
  Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
  Measuredwidth = d.getWidth();
  Measuredheight = d.getHeight();
}
```

and it does not compile. :(

```
Call requires API level 13 (current min is 4): android.view.Display#getSize
```

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "compile error" is actually a Lint error.

The [Lint API Check](http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck) article has a lot of info available.

You can "mark" code as targeting a newer version of the API by simply annotating the code with a @TargetApi annotation.

That way you can keep your minSdkVersion and support older versions of Android.

Comment: Strange that I have to extract it into a function to use the `@TargetApi`tag.

Answer (score -3):

you could do it like this:

```
int Measuredwidth = 0;
int Measuredheight = 0;

Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
try {
    Method method = d.getClass().getMethod("getSize", Point.class);
    method.invoke(defaultDisplay, point);
    Measuredwidth = size.x;
    Measuredheight = size.y;

} catch (Exception e) {

}
if (Measuredwidth == 0){
    Measuredwidth = d.getWidth();
    Measuredheight = d.getHeight();
}
```